# Use of custom argument specifiers for expl3 functions

Tags: macros, expl3, arguments

This question is highly opinion-based, but I think it might still be interesting to people writing new packages using the `expl3` API.

`expl3` currently defines several argument specifiers to indicate the usage of arguments for the various functions. Beside the hint to the user what argument types are expected, this also gives the impression that the same function supports overloaded arguments, i.e. has a slightly different behavior depending on what kind of argument type is being used.

The currently supported specifiers are `cDefFnNopTvVwx`, i.e. only 14 out of 52 possible letters do have a dedicated meaning.

Especially when dealing with custom data types, the use of `n` for various arguments that are actually of different type (not from a syntactic perspective, but from a semantic one) can quickly make the usage of functions harder than it would have to be. Using custom specifiers beyond the set fixed by the `expl3` API would, in my opinion, be quite useful to better distinguish semantically different arguments.

For example, the functions from `l3regex` would benefit from using `r` for non-compiled and `R` for pre-compiled regex arguments as opposed to the currently used `n` and `N` specifiers, to make it more clear which argument is the regex and which is the token list to match on.

At the moment, I can see two major problems with introducting custom specifiers:

1. Different packages would sooner or later use the same specifiers for different types. I don't think this would be a big problem, because by sticking to the recommended naming scheme the package name would be included in every package function, so the user already has a hint about in what namespace, so to say, the used specifiers are defined.
2. Using custom specifiers would break in the current system for generating new function variants, as this requires a mapping from a "fancy" specifier to one of the base specifiers `n` and `N`. Providing a new API function that specifies this mapping shouldn't be too hard to implement, but because of the above problem it would probably require a localized solution, as two packages could use the same specifier for two different bases.

Do you see other problems that using custom specifiers would cause? Do you think custom specifiers would be useful at all or would they cause more problems than being of any help?

Comment: `n` is for a braced argument; there are `\regex_replace_once:nnN` and `\regex_replace_once:NnN` (perhaps also the second argument could have `N`). I don't see any advantage in introducing semantic symbols: the existing ones specify the *syntax* of the expected argument. With `V` (or `v`) we get the value of the variable instead of the variable itself; this is similar to `efx`, where the expanded argument is passed. Actually, nothing prevents you from defining `\regex_replace:srN`, if you so desire. But why?

Comment: Minor nitpick: `:D` isn't supported, it's just _defined_, since the letter implies "Do not use". Also `:w` doesn't have a formal definition besides "what doesn't fit anywhere else". Of course you know that, just saying for the record :-)

Comment: @egreg Because it's easier to derive the usage of a function. From the signature of `\regex_replace_once:nnN` you don't immediately see which of the two `n`s is the regex and which is the token list. Using e.g. `:rnN` instead would make it much clearer. Also, I don't agree that the signature is only a syntactic hint, the syntax of e.g. `x` and `n` parameters is the same, the difference here is clearly a semantic one. Or think of `\char_set_catcode:nn`. The first parameter isn't actually a char but a charcode, which could be reflected by `:ii`.

Comment: My point simply is: If we already have to add the full signature on every function call, why not putting more semantic information into it to help the programmer?

Comment: Well if you are consequent this would mean that you would have to use  `\int_set:Ii` and `\prop_set:Pkv`. There are lots of argument type around -- actually almost every command has a specific argument. I don't think that it makes really sense to try to code every type in the signature.

Comment: Pushing things a bit further: `\int_set:Nn` would be replaced by `\set:Ii` and `\prop_set:Nnn` would be replaced by `\set:Pkv`.
For your personal usage, you can define your own signature semantic. Of course, `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` and `\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn` will no longer work. It is no problem for the former with a straightforward help of `\exp_args:N...` functions. The latter is a bit more complicated.